# How to reverse the redirecting output action in CPP?

Tags: c++, iostream, ostream

This seems a bit funny to me when I see this problem:

```
cout.rdbuf(cerr.rdbuf());
```

Yeah, successfully redirected the normal output to error output stream. But here's the nightmare, I wanted to `REVERSE` this (stupid) action. But `cerr.rdbuf(cout.rdbuf());` doesn't help after the first command has ran. i.e. there's no change in the outputting stream.

> How can that be done in C++?

("that" is redirecting the `normal output stream` back to itself (umm) and seperate it from the `error output stream`)

Comment: Look it up. It's easy to find.

Comment: Sorry? What does that mean?

Comment: The original stream buffer obtained through `cout.rdbuf()` can be saved in a variable. Is that the question?

Comment: It means **do some research**. You might start by looking up what `std::basic_ostream::rdbuf()` does. Hint: the first place I looked had an example that you could build from.

Comment: Hey, I'm not that kind of person who only ask questions and doesn't think or research before that. I simply ask this because I lack ideas, not because I don't want to think about it.

Comment: Anyway, I'll try it out with your tip, thanks.

Comment: OMG, I've just tried out your method @PeteBecker and I've found out my question is really stupid. Oops, sorry for bothering, LOL. Your suggestion about **[looking up what `std::basic_ostream::rdbuf()` does]** is really useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/rdbuf/

`streambuf * some_name = cout.rdbuf();` to store your original address of the normal output stream.

`cout.rdbuf(some_name);` to **restore**.

This also works on other types of stream. (Although it also works for the input stream, there's no reason to do that.)